# Best way to use hidden-xs and visible-xs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, hidden

I've got some code that displays a list of items with a vertical line to the left of the items. The vertical line is triggered by the snippet1-sections class contained in the div definition below.

If I want the vertical line to appear on tablets and desktops but not on phones, what is the best way to set this up without repeating the whole list of items for the phone version? Can I do it in the css?

```
<div class="row-fluid snippet1-sections">

   My list of items...

</div>
```

css:

```
.snippet1-sections{
    background:url('../../graphics/snippet1-vertical-divider.jpg') center center repeat-y;
}
```

Comment: My code didn't display properly in my initial post. Here it is again:

<div class="row-fluid snippet1-sections">
    My list of items in here
</div>

css:
.snippet1-sections{
    background:url('../../graphics/snippet1-vertical-divider.jpg') center center repeat-y;
}

Comment: There is an edit button under the question, press that and edit your question replacing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this class from bootstrap on the vertical line  `.hidden-xs`
in this way `class= "hidden-xs"`